# Why my exported function is not a function?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Consider the following example:

```
// bar.js
const foo = require('./foo');    

module.exports = function(args){
    let f = foo(args)
}
// foo is not a function
```

Then:

```
// bar.js
module.exports = function(args){
    let f = require('./foo')(args)
}
// behaves as expected
```

foo.js looks like:

```
const bar = require('./bar');  
module.exports = function(args){ //same args as bar.js
    const foo = {};
    foo.f1 = function(arg){
        console.log("Hi")
    }

    return foo
};
```

Comment: The code for `foo` would most definitely **not** be "unnecessary code".

Comment: I updated the question with more code

Comment: @znat Yeah, that's what I expected, see my answer for an explanation and solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are dealing with the problems of cyclic dependencies. I guess `foo.js` looks somehow like this:

```
const bar = require('./bar');

module.exports = function(args) {
  console.log(args);
};
```

Let's follow the steps the VM performs to execute the code (assuming you load `foo.js` first):

1. Load `foo.js`. Initialize exports with `A = {}`.
2. Load `bar.js`. Initialize exports with `B = {}`. Now within `bar.js`:

   1. `bar.js` requires the exports of `foo.js` (which are still `A = {}`), so set `foo` in `bar.js` to `A = {}` (this is the problem!).
   2. Replace the exports of `bar.js` with the function as declared.
3. Replace the exports of `foo.js` with the function as declared.

As you can see, there is no way for the VM to keep track of the exports of `foo.js` within `bar.js` if you use cyclic dependencies.

In your second example, you resolve the exports of `foo.js` later, when the function is called. At that point, the exports of `foo.js` have already been replaced with the function, and it works.

---

Short version: This is what happens.

1. The VM loads `foo.js` and initializes the exports of `foo.js` with object `A`.
2. The VM loads `bar.js` and initializes the exports of `bar.js` with object `B`.
3. The VM sets the variable `foo` in `bar.js` to the exports of `foo.js`, therefore `foo = A`.
4. The VM replaces the exports of `bar.js` with the function `C`
5. The VM sets the variable `bar` in `foo.js` to the exports of `bar.js`, therefore `bar = C`.
6. The VM replaces the exports of `foo.js` with the function `D`.

As you can see again, the variable `foo` in `bar.js` is still `A`, even though it should be `D`.

---

You will usually want to **avoid using cyclic dependencies**. If it is really necessary, then do not replace `module.exports`, but rather attach properties to the object:

```
module.exports.doBarAction = function(args){
    let f = foo.doFooAction(args)
};
```

This solves the problem as the object is still the same at runtime.
However, in most situations it is better to get rid of cyclic dependencies, at least as long as we are talking about CommonJS modules.

Comment: That was hard to understand for a Java programmer :)

Comment: @znat Yeah, Java performs a static compilation, allowing the compiler to resolve cyclic dependencies without problems, but the JavaScript VM does not. Don't try to compare `require()` with `import`.